# Mysql: Connection refused ERROR: 111

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mariadb

I can't connect to my server when I use a remote IP address.

Localhost is working fine.

**Some info:**

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Database: MariaDB

Port 3306 is open

User has remote (%) access.

I've changed `bind-address` in `50-server.conf` to `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` and I tried commenting it out. none of them worked. Also tried putting `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`in `my.conf` under a `[mysqld]` grouptag. After every change I restarted Mysql and tried to connect with this command `mrsql -u root -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p`. It works fine for localhost, but does not work when I try my servers IP.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked iptables and selinux?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: What does `netstat -lnp | grep mysql` show after MySQL starts?

Answer (score -1):

Already solved it.

Restarting my server solved the problem.